# How to solve "Unhandled exception type ClassNotFoundException" and "Vector is a raw type" errors?

Tags: java, servlets, applet

In servlet side, I am trying to receive an vector sent from the applet. The code is like

```
InputStream in = request.getInputStream();
ObjectInputStream inputFromApplet = new ObjectInputStream(in);
Vector v = (Vector) inputFromApplet.readObject();
```

But the compiler specifies that the following one is wrong.

```
Vector v = (Vector) inputFromApplet.readObject();
```

The error message is

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> - Unhandled exception type ClassNotFoundException
> - Vector is a raw type. References to generic type Vector
>   should be parameterized
> - Vector is a raw type. References to generic type Vector
>   should be parameterized

What's wrong with my code? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the exception, wrap your code in

```
try {
   <your code here>
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
   <code that happens when class can't be found>
}
```

The other messages are warnings which won't stop your program from compiling. They refer to needing a parameter on parametrised types to adhere to new specifications (as of Java 1.5). So, if you want to store integers in a Vector, use `Vector<Integer>`. This changes the methods to requiring `Integers` instead of the generic `Object` you'd normally get and increases type-safeness.

Answer (score 1):

You want to specify a datatype for vector -- e.g.

```
Vector<String> v = ...
```

String might not be the best choice for your application, however.

Comment: You can't use a primitive data type as a generic argument.

Comment: Good catch -- changed from int to String.